# RecyclerView reads wrong objects

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

im making an app that has 2 recycler views, first recycler view contains list of games and second recycler view contains fields of chosen game. I had two separeted nav graphs for each recycler views, but recently i decided to combine them to one nav graph, and since then i have problem with second recycler view which is showing all possible fields not only for chosen game.

The problem is that fieldsList from adapter suddenly loads all possible fields. When i set data it shows correct answer, but on onCreateViewHolder it loads fieldsList with all fields from all games.

There is code of ListFieldsFragment:

```
class ListFieldsFragment : Fragment(), SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, MenuProvider {
    private val args by navArgs<ListFieldsFragmentArgs>()
    private lateinit var mFieldViewModel: FieldViewModel
    private val adapter: ListFieldsAdapter by lazy { ListFieldsAdapter(args.currentGame) }
    private var _binding: FragmentListFieldsBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentListFieldsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root

        activity?.addMenuProvider(this, viewLifecycleOwner)

        val recyclerView = binding.fieldsRecyclerView
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())


        mFieldViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[FieldViewModel::class.java]
        mFieldViewModel.readGameWithFields(args.currentGame.gameId).observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { gameWithFieldsList ->
            gameWithFieldsList?.let {
                if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
                    adapter.setData(it[0].fields)
                }
            }
        }

        binding.fieldFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
            val action = ListFieldsFragmentDirections.actionListFieldsFragmentToAddFieldFragment(
                args.currentGame
            )
            findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
        binding.fieldFloatingActionButton.setOnLongClickListener {
            insertExampleDataToDatabase(args.currentGame.gameId)
            true
        }


        return view
    }
```

There is code for adapter:

```
class ListFieldsAdapter(game: Game) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListFieldsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    private var fieldsList = emptyList<Field>()
    private val currentGame = game

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {}

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.create_field_row, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return fieldsList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = fieldsList[position]
        holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.number_textView).text = currentItem.number.toString()
        holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.entry_textView).text = currentItem.entry
        holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.question_textView).text = currentItem.question
        holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.correctAnswer_textView).text = currentItem.correctAnswer
        holder.itemView.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.field_row).setOnClickListener {
            val action = ListFieldsFragmentDirections.actionListFieldsFragmentToUpdateFieldFragment(
                currentItem, currentGame
            )
            holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }


    }

    fun setData(fields: List<Field>) {
        fieldsList = fields
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Do you know where the problem is? And how to solve it?